# Can anybody see answers that I've deleted?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, privileges

When I delete an answer, I still see it and have the option to undelete it. Can anybody else see my deleted answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Moderators and users having 10k+ rep [can see deleted posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Deleted posts look like this for instance:

[image: deleted post]

But you cannot search for deleted posts.

Comment: If they have the link. And otherwise moderators can.

Comment: @Bart: Answers don't require the link, questions do. Answers can be viewed "normally" when you view the questions, for 10k+ users.

Comment: D'oh, true @MadaraUchiha. Somehow that converted to "questions" in my head. .... Coffee it is...